# Json parsing contain string of closing connection

Tags: json, parsing

I created a web service that returns a badly written json composed by a string 
within the json parsing

here the json:

```
[ { "Sigla":"OCF" , "codDeposito":1 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Spedizione Fano" }  , { "Sigla":"OCP" , "codDeposito":3 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Pesaro" }  , { "Sigla":"OCCE" , "codDeposito":7 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Cesena" }  , { "Sigla":"OCG" , "codDeposito":10 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Grosseto" }  , { "Sigla":"OCFB" , "codDeposito":13 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine(NO SPEDIZIONE) cliente Fano Banco" }  , { "Sigla":"OCVA" , "codDeposito":19 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Varese" }  , { "Sigla":"OC20" , "codDeposito":20 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Pescara" }  , { "Sigla":"OC24" , "codDeposito":24 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Firenze sud" }  , { "Sigla":"OC26" , "codDeposito":26 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Mestre" }  , { "Sigla":"OC33" , "codDeposito":33 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente RomaS" }  , { "Sigla":"OC36" , "codDeposito":36 , "descrizioneSigla":"Ordine cliente Pisa" }  , { "Sigla":"OC40" , "codDeposito":40 , "descrizion* Connection #0 to host 192.40.10.3 left intact * Closing connection #0 eSigla":"Ordine cliente Brescia" }  ]
```

The wrong message is connection #0 to host 192.40.10.3 ...

I call the web service with the command

curl -v -H 'token: tokenvalue' 'http:.........'

I do not know what generates that message

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. It would be useful to also have some more context about the question

Comment: The json contains a wrong string " * connection to host....... * " for web services 
that return only one line it is not shown

Comment: but for the other yes